# syntax error "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, syntax, compiler-errors

Why does my following code produce the following while compiling:   error: 'Individual' in class 'Evolve' does not name a type.

```
#ifndef EVOLVE_H
#define EVOLVE_H
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Operator.h"
#include "Individual.h"

using namespace std;

class Evolve
{
public:
    Evolve(int length, Operator** operators, int numOperators);

    Individual* bestIndividual;
    Individual* run(int generations);
    Operator operatorArray[];

private:
    int length; 
    int numOperators;   
};
#endif
```

And my class file is

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Evolve.h"
#include "Operator.h"
#include "Individual.h"

using namespace std;

Evolve::Evolve(int length, Operator** operators, int numOperators)
{
    Individual* bestIndividual = new Individual(length);
}

Evolve::Individual* run(int generations)
{
    for(int i=0; i<generations; i++)
    {
        cout << "test counter = " << i << endl;
    }
}
```

I've read a few other posts about the error and it has all been about what order to declare the function, but I'm not sure if thats the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The way you implement member function is incorrect.

Update:

```
Evolve::Individual* run(int generations)
```

to:

```
Individual* Evolve::run(int generations)
```

Also, to initialize member you do not re-define it again.

```
Evolve::Evolve(int length, Operator** operators, int numOperators)
: bestIndividual(new Individual(length)
{
}
```

In your constructor,

```
Individual* bestIndividual = new Individual(length);
```

you defined a local pointer `bestIndividual` and it leaks memory.

Answer (score 0):

The general syntax is:

```
return-type class-name :: function-name(arg list)

Individual*  Evolve    :: run          (int generations)
```

Fix your `Evolve` definition